# How to remove link tag

Tags: jquery, html

Update:  Hi, I can call an id of the link css that are included on head of my site, and use remove() or empty href onload function to remove it, and the effects actually are removed but somehow google page insight still shows that css, here is my code, is there away to remove it before it was added to my site by plugin?

```
  jQuery(window).load(function () {
    jQuery('#font-css').attr('href', ''); or
    jQuery('#font-css').remove();
  });
```

Hi because I need to check all current css that are included in my site (wordpress), and delete it hopefully to combine and include it again in footer (for removing render block in google page speed test).
First, I want to print it to check what is that css. (it maybe from many themes and plugins, I can not find it manually).

This is my jquery to print it but it does not show anything, Please help me.

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $string = '';
      jQuery('head link').each(function(i, obj) {
        $string += jQuery(this).html() + '   ';
      });
      alert('' +  $string);
  });
```

I want to see something like this :

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle1.css"> (if I found this one I want to remove it or at least check href to know where it is, please help me if you know how to do it).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply do this :)

**HTML**

```
<p class="test"></p>
```

**JQuery**

```
  $(document).ready(function($){
      $('link').each(function(i, obj) {
        $(this).attr('href', ''); //replaces 'href' value to empty string
        $('.test').append($(this));
        alert($(this));
      });
  });
```

`.html()` will not work for a `<link>` tag. Moreover do not use `.html()` because then in each loop iteration you will be replacing the previous link value with the new value. Meaning you will be left with only the last value instead of all the values. Use append/prepend instead(**which 'adds' to the existing values and not 'replace' the existing value**)

Comment: Hi, That maybe a great way to remove it, thank you, but I really need to detect the one needs to be removed first. can I print it on screen?

Comment: Yes you can, where do you want it to be printed on the screen -anywhere in the body or replace that whole link with a text ?

Comment: Yes  .html()` will not work for a `<link>` tag. Updated the answer to `append` the values in HTML. *Note: Do not use `html()` because for every loop you will be replacing the previous link value with the new value*. Use append/prepend instead

Comment: I can find it now and be able to remove it, thank you so much

Comment: Awesome .. Cheers

Comment: Please add some explanation of why this code helps the OP to answer itself, not in comments. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [answer] for more information.